# Which is faster for large layouts? CSS3, or jQuery?

Tags: jquery, css, css-transitions, css-animations

I've got a fluid layout on my site, with one element animated and having a transition on hover. The main problem is that on wider screens (say, wider than around 1600px), the CSS3 hover transition gets visibly choppy, and starts devouring memory. Would using jQuery to accomplish this make the effect faster on larger displays?

Comment: It probably depends a lot on browser and device, but from personal experience, I'd say JavaScript in general is slower than CSS.

Comment: I'd highly suspect that the browser's native CSS renderer is faster, but why are you asking us instead of testing it yourself?

Comment: I would prefer jQuery over css3 although css3 would be *slightly* faster as jQuery has more browser support...

Comment: It seems like a site/page specific issue. I have several sites which rely heavily on CSS3 where as a few which on jquery and both seems to work fine. If you can post the url, the problem can be better judged.

Comment: @MattBall I figured that the issue might be limited to my computer, and that the StackOverflow community could provide more insight based on experience (a larger sample size).

Comment: CSS is almost always going to be faster in general. However if you have effects, especially box-shadow, on the element being animated you may see a lot of slowdown.

Comment: @Sidharth Mudgal: How on earth did you arrive at the conclusion that browser support is relevant (or inversely proportional) to performance?!

Comment: @Verandaguy: Yes, it's highly dependent on the browser and its environment. There's no one-size-fits-all answer to this, although it's generally agreed-upon that JS is slower.

Comment: @BoltClock I guess you you misunderstood me. I meant "I would prefer jQuery over css3 as jQuery has more browser support although css3 would be slightly faster as jQuery". Sorry for wrongly phrasing it...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**EDIT:** Check out this [animation speed test](http://www.greensock.com/js/speed.html) that gives you a live comparison of the [GreenSock Animation Platform](http://www.greensock.com/)'s performance against a handful of other libraries capable of animation (including jQuery). The TweenLite (GreenSock) performance is actually quite impressive, especially compared to Zepto's CSS3-based animations.

--

In terms of performance, CSS3 animations are much faster than jQuery animations. ([Source](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/css3-vs-jquery-animations/))

> The huge difference in performance is because the browser's CSS processor is written in C++ and native code executes very fast whereas jQuery (JavaScript) is an interpreted language and the browser can't predict JavaScript ahead in time, in terms of what event will occur next.

However, as expressed in the article, jQuery is much better at browser compatibility, as CSS3 transitions are not supported by IE<=9

Comment: Also, [this article](http://chrissilich.com/blog/fix-css-animation-slow-or-choppy-in-mobile-browsers/) may be relevant.

Comment: It seems MooTools outperforms the competition in Webkit- and Gecko-based browsers.

Answer (score 3):

CSS3 is much faster. It uses native browser animations instead of javascript timer. CSS3 animations can also be GPU accelerated.

But its no silver bullet, if your page is slow you need to optimize it. The timeline tab in Chrome Dev Tools provides good hints of what is causing the slowness. You might also enable the "Composited render layer borders" under chrome://flags. That option shows which element is being GPU accelerated

Its possible that your hover transition is triggering GPU acceleration in the whole website therefore causing the slowness. If thats the case, some well placed z-index might avoid the problem.